# Reference request: strong polynomial-time for LP

Tags: linear-programming, survey

A follow-up of sorts on this question:
[Complexity of finding a consistent hyperplane](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40348/complexity-of-finding-a-consistent-hyperplane)

What is a good survey of partial results on the strong poly-time status of the general LP problem?